# ImageButton's image is blurry after setLayoutParams

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have looked around here and elsewhere, but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I'm no stranger to Java, although this is my first android application.

I'm displaying 3 ImageButtons (one right over the other), which will need to be resized to fit any screen (ie, 7-10'' tablet to 4'' phone). I have this logic figured out, but the problem I'm running into is the quality of the images on 7''+ devices is TERRIBLE. Here's the code for my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_god"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/godtext" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_growth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/growthtext" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_service"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/servicetext" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the relevant part of my activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int version = VERSION.SDK_INT;
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    if (version < 13){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    } else {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    }

    /**
     * Creating all buttons instances
     * */
    // Dashboard God button
    ImageButton btn_god = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_god);
    btn_god.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btn_god.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height/4;
    params.width = params.height;
    btn_god.setLayoutParams(params);

    // Dashboard Growth button
    ImageButton btn_growth = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_growth);
    btn_growth.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    params = btn_growth.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height/4;
    params.width = params.height;
    btn_growth.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn_growth.setImageResource(R.drawable.growthtext);

    // Dashboard Service button
    ImageButton btn_service = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_service);
    btn_service.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    params = btn_service.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height/4;
    params.width = params.height;
    btn_service.setLayoutParams(params);
```

What I WANT to do is to take a high resolution image, and downsize it to fit the smaller screens. However, it seems like it's taking the low resolution image and up scaling it for the larger screens. Has anyone ran across a similar issue? How did you solve it? I appreciate any responses!

Comment: Do you know, that in android application you can provide different images for different screen sizes? There are folders in the resources directory of android project. They are drawable-xhdpi, drawable-ldpi etc. I suggest you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Also let us know if it works out for you. We can put it as an answer.

Comment: Where did you place the drawables (in which folder)? Which 7 inch + devices are we talking about here, what's their DPIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline    density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

here this is what i got off this site, maybe it will help

Comment: My numbers were more than a little off. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawables folders, you can declare different images for different screen densities.  I would do a good read of [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Basically, you're going to need to declare separate drawable folders with different suffixes for different screen sizes.  For example, for extra-high density screen resolutions, you'll need a drawable-xhdpi folder with all of your high-resolution images inside.  Android will automatically select the correct image based on the screen density of the device.

Comment: I have seen that article, and have already done this, but the issue is still happening. I even tried to remove the lower dpi images to force the OS to take the higher dpi images, but that didn't work either. I'm wondering if the OS scales the image down to fit the size of the ImageButtons?